# Does Swagger-UI or OpenAPI-generator support headers for each part of a multipart request?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, openapi-generator

Take the following openapi spec file and paste it into editor.swagger.io or run it through openapi-generator in the language of your choice:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: whatever
  title: whatever
paths:
  /something:
    post:
      responses:
        200: 
         description: Successful operation
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                stringpart:
                  type: string
                  format: uuid
                binarypart:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
            encoding:
              binarypart:
                headers: 
                  X-Custom-Header:
                    description: This is a custom header
                    schema:
                      type: string
```

Why is there no reference to `X-Custom-Header` anywhere? There is no place to set it in the UI render, and no reference to it in any generated code. As far as I can tell, this is valid openapi3 schema, according to the examples I found here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/

Answer (score 1):

Swagger UI currently [does not support](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5356) the `encoding` attribute of `multipart` requests.

Comment: that's unfortunate. I suppose it must be the same story for the codegen tooling.